# Do derivative works of Creative Commons BY-NC works also have to be noncommercial?

Tags: copyright, legal, creative-commons

I've created an image that uses some source images that have been released under a [Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 US](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/deed.en_US) license. This license is not a share-alike license, meaning that derivative works do not need to be released under the same license.

I was wondering, however, if I could also release my derivative work to the public domain and use it commercially, or whether that would count as "using the BY-NC work commercially". I don't actually plan on doing so just yet, but I've never gotten a straight answer to this question since most people who include the non-commercial clause also have the share-alike or no-derivative-works clause in there as well.

It seems to me personally like it *wouldn't* count, just because the clause doesn't put any explicit restrictions on derivative works like the addition of a share-alike or no-derivative-works  clause would and it doesn't seem in the spirit of Creative Commons to include implicit restrictions like a cascading non-commercial requirement. However, I'd like to make sure before I accidentally do something that unintentionally infringes the license.

Comment: https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Defining_Noncommercial we are not lawyers by the way

Comment: I know you're not lawyers, and I'd never seen that link before.

Comment: ugh wrong link http://creativecommons.org/weblog/entry/17127

Comment: However, I couldn't think of a better place to post this question; this was the only place I could find that was relevant.

Comment: anyway its a bit fuzzy stuff and you can only ever really pinpoint it in your case by asking a court. Nifty huh. Lawyers making rules on the go. Anyway i would say this is slightly offtopic, even tough relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I am not a lawyer. You should get one, if you are concerned about possible legal issues.</sub>

---

Of course, they have. You just cannot grant more rights than you have obtained, so there is no option for you to release a derivative work as a whole¹ to the public domain, or under any [free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)/libre license, or in general any license, that is *more permissive* than CC-BY-NC. However, you could release it under *more restrictive* license, such as CC-BY-NC-ND for example. If the license of original work were [copyleft](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/) one (i. e. *-SA), you could not do the latter – that’s the difference.

---

¹ If it’s technically possible to represent your part of the work separately from original work, you may put it under CC0 or CC-BY, but the result, as long as it includes CC-BY-NC’ed part, still shall be covered by CC-BY-NC. It actually makes perfect sense if your part of work might be useful out of context of that non-free image.

Comment: I can see why Creative Commons considers NC harmful now - because of misunderstandings like this one. Thanks!